# PowerPoint VBA paste png when notes area selected

Tags: vba, png, powerpoint

my code

```
PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPastePNG
```

works fine, but sometimes I leave my cursor active in the notes area and get an error (Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request. The specified data types in unavailable.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF9NV.png)

Any idea how to go around it?

Comment: Can you include the rest of your code for more context?

Comment: I am actually exporting a chart from excel workbook to presentation as png.


    Template_Path="C:/template.pptx"
    Set Active_Slide = NewPowerPoint.Presentations.Open(Template_Path).Slides(1)
   set Main_Worksheet = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    Main_Worksheet.ChartObjects(Chart_Names(i)).Copy
    Active_Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPastePNG

Comment: Try adding this line just before the Active_Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial line:  ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.